# DocumentDB, Is it possible to call UDF from within a SP?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb, udf

In Azure DocumentDB, is it possible to call UDF from within a SP ?

Comment: Vote
[here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/16267270-allow-to-use-udf-user-defined-function-inside-a-d) to add this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported. However, you can include your UDF code as a function within the sproc itself. [documentdb-utils](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#support-for-require-in-server-side-scripts) has functionality for modularly including code into sprocs so you can maintain DRY principles.